# connect to walletconnect with Dapp

Tags: frontend, metamask, wallet-connect

I created my own lottery smart contract and also created front ends Dapp in html and javascript. I before used metamask for connecting. and also I used infura for connecting without metamask. but now I want to connect the project to trust wallet in phone with walletconnect. But I cannot find true code for connecting dapp to trust wallet with walletconnect. Please someone help me to connect html front end to the trust wallet with Qr-code. If you need to see my project I can send all code of my project for you.

I used before this code for wallet connect:

```html
<div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h5>Web3modal example for vanille JavaScript and HTML</h5>

                  <p>No wallet connected. Connect wallet to show accounts and their ETH balances.</p>

                  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alert-error-https" style="display: none">
                    You can run this example only over HTTPS connection.
                  </div>

                  <div id="prepare">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-connect">
                      Connect wallet
                    </button>
                  </div>

                  <div id="connected" style="display: none">

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-disconnect">
                      Disconnect wallet
                    </button>

                    <hr>

                    <div id="network">
                      <p>
                        <strong>Connected blockchain:</strong> <span id="network-name"></span>
                      </p>

                      <p>
                        <strong>Selected account:</strong> <span id="selected-account"></span>
                      </p>

                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <h4>All account balances</h4>

                    <table class="table table-listing">
                      <thead>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>ETH balance</th>
                      </thead>

                      <tbody id="accounts">
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <p>Please try to switch between different accounts in your wallet if your wallet supports this functionality.</p>

                  </div>

                  <br>

                  <div class="well">
                    <p class="text-muted">See also the <a href="https://web3modal.com/">TypeScript and React example application</a></p>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- We use simple <template> templating for the example -->
            <div id="templates" style="display: none">
              <template id="template-balance">
                <tr>
                  <th class="address"></th>
                  <td class="balance"></td>
                </tr>
              </template>
            </div>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/web3@1.2.11/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/web3modal@1.9.0/dist/index.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/evm-chains@0.2.0/dist/umd/index.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/@walletconnect/web3-provider@1.2.1/dist/umd/index.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/fortmatic@2.0.6/dist/fortmatic.js"></script>

            <!-- This is our example code -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./example.js"></script>
```

and also this code for normal connect :

```js
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') 
            {
                console.log('MetaMask is installed!');
                
web333 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);            
                
            const accountsH = ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            const accountH = accountsH[0];
            const showAccountH = document.querySelector('.showAccount');
                
        const accounts = ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
        const account = accounts[0];
        const showAccount = document.querySelector('.showAccount'); 
                
            }else{
                console.log('MetaMask not installed!');
                alert("Please install Metamsk wallet first, then try again");
                
                
     web333 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/3c68/* my infura ID */5811f301753"));              
}


var addressH = "0x35C00a/*MY CONTRACT ADDRESS */8D639145";
                var abiH =[/*my contract ABI*/];
                        contractH = new web333.eth.Contract(abiH, addressH);
```

I want to connect trust wallet and metamask and can connect to the other wallet. I want the global type of code for all wallets.

Comment: Please some body help me about wallet connect . I can not  use it in my project in html and java scripts.

Comment: What is infura ID? Cause when I create a new project on infura, it gives me a project ID but, I want to use TrustWallet on my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h5>Web3modal example for vanille JavaScript and HTML</h5>

                  <p>No wallet connected. Connect wallet to show accounts and their ETH balances.</p>

                  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="alert-error-https" style="display: none">
                    You can run this example only over HTTPS connection.
                  </div>

                  <div id="prepare">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-connect">
                      Connect wallet
                    </button>
                  </div>

                  <div id="connected" style="display: none">

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-disconnect">
                      Disconnect wallet
                    </button>

                    <hr>

                    <div id="network">
                      <p>
                        <strong>Connected blockchain:</strong> <span id="network-name"></span>
                      </p>

                      <p>
                        <strong>Selected account:</strong> <span id="selected-account"></span>
                      </p>

                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <h4>All account balances</h4>

                    <table class="table table-listing">
                      <thead>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>ETH balance</th>
                      </thead>

                      <tbody id="accounts">
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <p>Please try to switch between different accounts in your wallet if your wallet supports this functionality.</p>

                  </div>

                  <br>

                  <div class="well">
                    <p class="text-muted">See also the <a href="https://web3modal.com/">TypeScript and React example application</a></p>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- We use simple <template> templating for the example -->
            <div id="templates" style="display: none">
              <template id="template-balance">
                <tr>
                  <th class="address"></th>
                  <td class="balance"></td>
                </tr>
              </template>
            </div>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/web3@1.2.11/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/web3modal@1.9.0/dist/index.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/evm-chains@0.2.0/dist/umd/index.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/@walletconnect/web3-provider@1.2.1/dist/umd/index.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/fortmatic@2.0.6/dist/fortmatic.js"></script>

            <!-- This is our example code -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./example.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).